# Is there a program that will launch a configurable context menu

Tags: command-line, application, menu, zenity

I'm looking for something like Zenity or Yad, except I want something that behaves like a menu, namely: it opens right next to the cursor; it takes one click to select things; it's possible to have multiple levels.

The closest thing I've found is actually Autokey's folders, but Autokey needs to always be running (even if I call `autokey-run`), which I'd prefer to avoid.

The key requirement is that I be able to *single click* on something that appears *near my cursor*.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't say about context menus, but `dmenu` and `xbindkeys` may be of use.

Comment: I'm aware of both. I'm not worried about how to actually bind the keys, and unfortunately, `dmenu` does not solve the problem; I need it to be accessible by mouse. See the edit.

Comment: Well, then first that comes to mind is openbox, blackbox, fluxbox, windowmaker etc., can't name a single standalone program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sawfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawfish_(window_manager)) manages its menus with a companion program `sawfish-menu`. You can use that program even if you aren't running Sawfish as your window manager. The protocol between sawfish and sawfish-menu doesn't seem to be documented anywhere; it's inspired from the [menu specification format](http://sawfish.tuxfamily.org/sawfish.html/Popup-Definitions.html#Popup-Definitions) in Sawfish itself.

```
echo '(popup-menu (("_toplevel" 0) ("_submenu" ("_foo" 1) () ("_bar" 2))))' |
/usr/lib/sawfish/1.5.3/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sawfish-menu
```

`sawfish-menu` prints `0` if the user selects “toplevel”, etc. You can specify strings (in double quotes, or even without quotes if they're valid Lisp identifiers) instead of numbers for the entries. If the user aborts (e.g. by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>) then the output is `()`.

Here's a summary of the input syntax of `sawfish-menu`.

- Start with `(popup-menu` and end with `)`.
- For a clickable menu entry, use `("TEXT" OUTPUT)` where *TEXT* is the text of the entry and *OUTPUT* is what the program prints if this menu entry is selected.

  - If there is an underscore in *TEXT*, the next character is the accelerator for that entry.
  - You can put a check mark in front of a menu entry by adding `(check . t)`, e.g. `("Foo" 42 (check . t))`.
  - You can put a bullet (radio button) in front of a menu entry by adding `(group . SOMETHING) (check . t)`. Only one entry within a given group can have the button.
  - You can make an entry be greyed out and non-selectable by adding `(insensitive . t)`.
- For a submenu, use `("TEXT" ENTRY…)`.
- For a separator, use `()`.

Obviously, don't expect people to have this utility installed. It's typically not packaged separately from Sawfish, but it doesn't actually need anything from Sawfish itself; it's a rep script, [rep](http://sawfish.tuxfamily.org/librep.html/index.html) being the Lisp dialect that Sawfish (and basically nothing else) is written in. On Debian, you need the `rep-gtk` package to run `sawfish-menu`, plus the script itself.

Comment: Thanks. This answers the question, so I accepted it; what I'm probably going to end up doing, though, is writing a python script for the specific menu I want. Looking at the source for `sawfish-menu` was illuminating.